# jQuery smooth scroll background image horizontally?

Tags: jquery

I have a banner towards the top of a development site. I have the image scrolling left-right with the jquery below. It's abit choppy and freezes when other jquery function are in use such as phishing or a jquery image rotator.

My question is, is there a better solution that will help scroll the image smoothly?

```
var $jg = jQuery.noConflict();
$jg(document).ready(function() {
    var xAdd = 0;
    var scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
        xAdd++;
        if(xAdd >= 1200){
            xAdd = 0;
        }
        $jg('#clouds').css('background-position',xAdd + 'px ');

    },100);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using jQuery's [$.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) like this:

```
var $jg = jQuery.noConflict();
$jg(document).ready(function() {
    // Animate Cloud Loop //
    function cloud_loop($target, val){        
        $target.animate({'background-position' : val+'px'}, 'fast', 'linear', function(){
            $target.css('background-position','0');                
            cloud_loop($target, val);
        });
    }

    // Start Animation Loop //
    cloud_loop($jg('#clouds'), 1200);
});
```

Use can change the 'fast' parameter in the function to 'slow' or a ms value for the complete animation.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: Tanks to Chad and Joseph for the 'linear'!

Comment: this worked great for the first 1000px, but then comes to a crawl and starts chopping up before hitting the 1200px.

Comment: @user949269 Take a look at the updated answer; getting a fiddle set up for you as well.

Comment: yes, this answer its much better, thank you!! But im still getting the crawl at 1000 or so px. Once it hits the loop, it starts up fast again.

Comment: Check what easing you have set as default or try manually setting an easing property on the animate to see if that changes that slowdown.

Comment: that's most likely because it's not using linear easing. try `$target.animate({'background-position' : val+'px'}, 'fast', 'linear', function(){...`

Comment: WOW! You guys rock!! The 'linear' worked :) I love Stackoverflow!

Comment: dSquared, Chad and Joseph you guys are geniuses!